# Html code to rotate text in rectangle box along with sides in wpcf7pdf

Tags: html, rotation, pdf-generation, parent-child, contact-form-7

Html code to rotate text in rectangle box along with sides in wpcf7pdf.

I am using rotate code works only in parent div only, not working in child div.
I need code along with rectangle sides.
And some html code not working in wpcf7pdf, plz help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.